# Determining if $z=\infty$ is an isolated singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis

From [here](https://xchen.math.gatech.edu/teach/comp_analysis/note-sing-infinity.pdf), it seems that $f(z)$ has an isolated singularity at $z=\infty$ if $f\left(z\right)$ is analytic in the exterior of the disk $\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\colon\,\left|z\right|<R\right\}$. It is later also claimed that $z=\infty$ is an isolated singularity of $f(z)$ iff $z=0$ is an isolated singularity of $f\left(1/z\right)$.

Now, I'm a bit confused here - say we have something like the following function

$$f\left(z\right) = \dfrac{z^2-2z}{(z+1)^2(z^2+4)}.$$

We can quickly confirm that $z=0$ is not an isolated singularity for $f\left(1/z\right)$. On the other hand, if we take $R = 2$, we can easily see that $f$ is analytic in the exterior of the corresponding disk and so, $z=\infty$ should be an isolated singularity. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that $z=\infty$ is not a singularity of $f(z)$ at all (or if you like, it is a *removable* singularity).  You can assign the value $f(\infty)=0$ and $f$ will be holomorphic at $\infty$ with no singularity there.  (What does "holomorphic at $\infty$" mean?  Well, the simple way to define it is to say the function $g(z)=f(1/z)$ will be holomorphic at $0$ if you assign $g(0)=0$, and this means $f$ is "holomorphic at $\infty$" with value $0$.  More abstractly, you can make $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ into a Riemann surface and talk about holomorphic functions on (open subsets of) that Riemann surface.)

Intuitively, the idea is that the numerator of $f$ grows like $z^2$ and the denominator grows like $z^4$ as $z\to\infty$, so $f(\infty)$ should be $1/\infty^2=0$.

Comment: Ah, interesting and, therefore, the residue there will also vanish. What if we instead consider the function $f(z) = e^z/(z^2+1)$? Indeed, we have the standard singularities at $z=\pm\dot{\imath}$ but for $z=\infty$, the limit doesn't exist (if we move along the positive and then the negative real axis). So, there would be a non-removable singularity there, no?

Comment: That will have an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: Wait, so how does one gauge it to be an essential singularity? Do we just consider the negative coefficients in the Laurent expansion? Or is there a quicker way to spot so?

Comment: Well, an isolated singularity that is not removable or a pole (i.e. the limit as you approach it does not exist as a value in $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$) is essential.  So it would be enough to just check that the limit does not exist.

Comment: OK, one last thing, and perhaps this is more of a "meta" question. I think I recall that for an isolated singularity to be a pole, the corresponding limit should "blow up" (i.e. go to infinity). However, since in $\mathbb{C}$, there is only "one" complex-infinity, blowing up here technically implies that the function approaches some value, not necessarily finite. This is the difference b/w the limit definitions of a pole and an essential singularity (where the latter requires the limit to actually not exist, i.e. have different values along certain different paths). Does that seem coherent?

Comment: Sure, you could think about it that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140084/discussion-between-gettingmathy-and-eric-wofsey).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say that $0$ is not an isolated singularity of $f(1/z)$?
It certainly must be some kind of singularity since $1/z$ is not defined at $z=0$ , so $f(1/z)$ is not a priori defined there either (we use different formulations when we work in the Riemann sphere rather than the complex plane, but the linked notes are about functions on $\mathbf{C}$, for which the previous staement is unproblematically true).

The point is that, since $f(1/z)$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$, the singularity at $0$ is removable, and so $f$ has a removable singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: that... actually makes good sense - thanks!